# Sencha Cmd no actualiza App.js a pesar de realizar cambios al código

Tags: cmd, extjs, sencha

Tengo un proyecto en ExtJS 6.6.0 y hasta hace una semana todo funcionaba bien.

Utilizo sencha app watch para que de manera automática me vaya recompilando los cambios, pero algo pasó que ahora, aunque haga cambios en cualquier archivo .js dentro del proyecto, los cambios no se ven reflejados al refrescar la página.

Ya se vació el caché en el navegador, se probó con otros navegadores, en PHP están los headers para evitar caché, en php.ini igual... todo apunta a que los cambios que estoy realizando no se están actualizando en app.js, por eso se carga la versión anterior siempre.

También observo que aunque en **app.json** tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:
`"indexHtmlPath": "main.php",` el archivo main.php no se actualiza al llamar **sencha app watch**.

Ya no sé qué hacer, he utilizado los comandos **sencha app refresh**, también **sencha app build development**, pero nada cambia en mi código cuando refresco la página.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Alguna sugerencia???

Comment: Ensaya `sencha app clean` y luego `sencha app build`. ¿Se ejecutan sin error?

Comment: Gracias Arthur, la verdad, nunca supe cual era la acusa del problema, y su solución también fue "rara"... bastó con que sobrescribiera app.js con una versión anterior de semanas atrás... ejecutara _sencha app build production_ y ya los cambios se registraran en app.js y ya no diera error, después utilizaba _sencha app watch_ y ya los cambios se reflejaban de manera correcta.